# MongoDB - How does it avoid full collection scan?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have this `users` collection with 1000000 rows.
The structure of each document is shown below by a call to `findOne`.
The indexes are shown too through a call to `getIndexes`. So I have
two compound indexes on it, only the order of their keys is different.

All the `username` values are unique in this collection,
they are of the form "user" + k, for k=0,1,2,...,999999.

Also, I don't have empty ages or usernames.

```
[test] 2014-03-08 20:08:10.135 >>> db.users.aggregate({'$match':{ 'username':{'$exists':false} }}) ;
{ "result" : [ ], "ok" : 1 }
[test] 2014-03-08 20:08:27.760 >>> db.users.aggregate({'$match':{ 'age':{'$exists':false} }}) ;
{ "result" : [ ], "ok" : 1 }
[test] 2014-03-08 20:08:41.198 >>> db.users.find({username : null}).count();
0
[test] 2014-03-08 20:12:01.456 >>> db.users.find({age : null}).count();
0
[test] 2014-03-08 20:12:06.790 >>>
```

What I don't understand in this `explain` I am running is the following:
How is MongoDB able to scan only 996291 document and to avoid scanning
the remaining 3709 documents. How is MongoDB sure he is not missing
any documents (from these 3709 ones) which match the query criterion?
I don't see how that is possible if we assume MongoDB is only using
the `username_1_age_1` index.

```
C:\>C:\Programs\MongoDB\bin\mongo.exe
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: test
Welcome to the MongoDB shell!
[test] 2014-03-08 19:31:41.683 >>> db.users.count();
1000000

[test] 2014-03-08 19:31:45.68 >>> db.users.findOne();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5318fac5e22bd6bc482baf88"),
        "i" : 0,
        "username" : "user0",
        "age" : 10,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-03-06T22:46:29.225Z")
}

[test] 2014-03-08 19:32:06.352 >>> db.users.getIndexes();
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "test.users",
                "name" : "_id_"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "age" : 1,
                        "username" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "test.users",
                "name" : "age_1_username_1"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "username" : 1,
                        "age" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "test.users",
                "name" : "username_1_age_1"
        }
]

[test] 2014-03-08 19:31:49.941 >>> db.users.find({"age" : {"$gte" : 21, "$lte" : 30}}).sort({"username" : 1}).hint({"username" : 1, "age" : 1}).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor username_1_age_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 167006,
        "nscannedObjects" : 167006,
        "nscanned" : 996291,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 167006,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 996291,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 3,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 3177,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "username" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ],
                "age" : [
                        [
                                21,
                                30
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "mongo020:27017"
}
[test] 2014-03-08 19:32:06.352 >>>
```

**UPDATE - Here is an exact description how to reproduce:**

```
C:\>mongo

C:\>C:\Programs\MongoDB\bin\mongo.exe
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: test
Welcome to the MongoDB shell!
[test] 2014-03-11 05:13:00.941 >>> function populate(){
...
... for (i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
...    db.users.insert({
...        "i" : i,
...        "username" : "user"+i,
...        "age" : Math.floor(Math.random()*60),
...         "created" : new Date()
...    }
...    );
... }
... }
[test] 2014-03-11 05:13:33.139 >>>
[test] 2014-03-11 05:15:46.689 >>> populate();
[test] 2014-03-11 05:16:46.366 >>> db.users.ensureIndex({username:1, age:1});
[test] 2014-03-11 05:17:05.476 >>>
[test] 2014-03-11 05:17:05.476 >>> db.users.count();
1000000
[test] 2014-03-11 05:18:35.297 >>> db.users.getIndexes();
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "test.users",
                "name" : "_id_"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "username" : 1,
                        "age" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "test.users",
                "name" : "username_1_age_1"
        }
]
[test] 2014-03-11 05:19:54.657 >>>
[test] 2014-03-11 05:19:54.657 >>> db.users.find({"age" : {"$gte" : 21, "$lte" : 30}}).sort({"username" : 1}).hint({"username" : 1, "age" : 1}).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor username_1_age_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 166799,
        "nscannedObjects" : 166799,
        "nscanned" : 996234,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 166799,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 996234,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 2,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 2730,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "username" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ],
                "age" : [
                        [
                                21,
                                30
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "mongo020:27017"
}
[test] 2014-03-11 05:20:44.15 >>>
```

Comment: Is the age and username filled in for all documents?

Comment: @Sammaye Yes. See please the updated the text above.

Comment: Is it possible that the size of a few of your indexed values is greater than 1024 bytes?  See [doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/) `MongoDB will not add that value to an index if it is longer than 1024 bytes`.

Comment: Are all of your usernames unique? If they aren't, that would explain it

Comment: @user602525 They are. See my comment on Neil's answer.

Comment: @AnandJayabalan I don't think I have anything bigger than 1K. See my comment on Neil's answer.

Comment: can you double-check that all your usernames are unique?  Also what is the range of ages - with all unique usernames and completely random ages I cannot reproduce this result, but then I'm using 2.6.0-rc1.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky The range of ages is [0, 59]. Yes, the usernames are unique, they are of the form "user" + k as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky See my update named "exact description how to reproduce" above. It is basically the book example (page 81 at the bottom). I've only replaced the number 120 with 60. http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028031.do

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a 2.4 bug.  Have you tried 2.6?

Comment: btw - I posted a more complete explanation in the mongodb-user group ( https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/2xnxC-9WFCU )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a 2.4 bug caused by this bit of [code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.4/src/mongo/db/btreecursor.cpp#L291):

```
// If nscanned is increased by more than 20 before a matching key is found, abort
// skipping through the btree to find a matching key.  This iteration cutoff
// prevents unbounded internal iteration within BtreeCursor::init() and
// BtreeCursor::advance() (the callers of skipAndCheck()).  See SERVER-3448.
if ( _nscanned > startNscanned + 20 ) {
    skipUnusedKeys();
    // If iteration is aborted before a key matching _bounds is identified, the
    // cursor may be left pointing at a key that is not within bounds
    // (_bounds->matchesKey( currKey() ) may be false).  Set _boundsMustMatch to
    // false accordingly.
    _boundsMustMatch = false;
    return;
}
```

and more imporantly [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.4/src/mongo/db/btreecursor.cpp#L88-L89):

```
//don't include unused keys in nscanned
//++_nscanned;
```

As you scan the index, you'll lose an increment of nscanned every time you have 20 consecutive misses.

You can reproduce with a very simple example:

```
> db.version()
2.4.8
>
> for (var i = 1; i<=100; i++){db.foodle.save({_id:i, name:'a'+i, age:1})}
> db.foodle.ensureIndex({name:1, age:1})
> db.foodle.find({ age:{ $gte:10, $lte:20 }}).hint({name:1, age:1}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor name_1_age_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
        "nscanned" : 96,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 96,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 1,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "name" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ],
                "age" : [
                        [
                                10,
                                20
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "Jeffs-MacBook-Air.local:27017"
}
```

If you change the ages so you don't get 20 misses, the value of nscanned is what you would expect:

```
for (var i = 1; i<=100; i++){
    var theAge = 1;
    if (i%10 == 0){ theAge = 15;}
    db.foodle.save({ _id:i, name:'a'+i, age: theAge });
}

{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor name_1_age_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 10,
        "nscannedObjects" : 10,
        "nscanned" : 100,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 10,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 100,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "name" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ],
                "age" : [
                        [
                                10,
                                20
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "Jeffs-MacBook-Air.local:27017"
}
```

I'm not sure why the increment is commented out, but this code has all been changed in 2.6 and should return the nscanned that you expect.

Comment: Great findings. Thanks for this detailed and to-the-point answer.

Comment: Sorry but I fail to see how this is a "bug" or that this is a relevant explanation. Despite the two main protagonists putting in their acceptance and vote. Can you please justify your position on this further? That does not seem to be unreasonable to ask.

Comment: Sure.  The original question is: Given a compound index with a leading key that is unique, why is nscanned less than the total number of documents if I force the use of the index without the leading key as a query predicate.  My response is that it should be, but isn't due to the issue described.  If you take the code he uses to reproduce the issue, or you change your example to have a unique leading key, and run it in 2.6, you'll see that nscanned is equal to the document count in both cases.

Comment: I wasn't "tagged" in your comment so did not see this till now. So as you say running the code (which was, ahem posted by me originally) it does indeed to a full scan and doesn't show selected bounds as described in 2.6. Yet as a result, the query takes considerably longer due to the full scan, so on test hardware 600ms compared to 200ms in the 2.4 result. Yet the match count is the same. So clearly more work is being done, but before the "fix" nothing was missed. I simply find that interesting.

Comment: So for posterity and for @peter.petrov and yourself, the actual "Bug" is in 2.6 [SERVER-13197](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13197) which I reported. The 2.6 release includes a major refactor of the Index interface, so part of the code that correctly detected the index bounds and produces the intended results as I explained, now no longer works without explicitly setting `MinKey` and `MaxKey` bounds on the first index element. As shown there you actually get the intended output when doing so. This is intended to be fixed in a future version.

Answer (score 1):

The correct "solution" is not to force the query optimizer to use an index that doesn't match its idea of a "qualifying" index, but instead include the leading field as well as the field you are constraining.  This has the advantage of using the index in **2.6** without the (hacky) "hint" (which might hurt your performance if you later add another index, on `{age:1,name:1}`.

Query:

```
db.names.find({ name:{$lt:MaxKey ,$gt:MinKey}, age: {$gte: 21, $lte: 30}},
              {_id:0, age:1, name:1}).explain()
```

2.6 explain:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor name_1_age_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 6010,
    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 6012,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 6012,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : true,
    "nYields" : 46,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 8,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "name" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ],
        "age" : [
            [
                21,
                30
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "Asyas-MacBook-Pro.local:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

2.4 explain (you have to add either `hint({name:1,age:1})` or `.sort({name:1,age:1})` to force use of the index:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor name_1_age_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 6095,
    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 6096,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 103,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 6199,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : true,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 10,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "name" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ],
        "age" : [
            [
                21,
                30
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "Asyas-MacBook-Pro.local:24800"
}
```

I added projection to show "indexOnly" is true in both cases, if you remove projection, the plans is identical but nscannedObjects becomes the same as n rather than 0.

Comment: Actually I would have thought the "correct" answer was to confirm that the behavior of using the index bounds is actually intended, as I did go to some length to explain. And that the "accepted" answer was actually false, pointing to code that intentionally "skipped" counting stale index entries, and the "Bug" was introduced in 2.6 as shown here: [SERVER-13197](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13197). Which also explains the workaround due to 2.6 not correctly picking up the bounds from the intended `sort` operation as shown in the question. An endorsement of that answer would be better

Comment: I don't think it would be better for someone who is looking to understand how to make the query use the index they thought their query would use.

Comment: (Sigh of exasperation) I believe the question is "How does this avoid a full collection scan". This content does not go any way to explain that, so that IMO does not help. Also an accepted answer saying "This is a bug", again IMO does not help. So apparently my opinion of trying to "help" is wrong. It seems a more popular approach to not help.

Answer (score 0):

This is really call about mongo "giving up" after it realizes that the matches that are possible have been exhausted, and there will be no more items to match. The index is helping here by providing some bounds.

Actually this is the part that explains it:

```js
"indexBounds" : {

          "age" : [
                    [
                            21,
                            30
                    ]
            ]
```

Since that is a field in the selected index, mongo has set bounds on where to **start** and where to **end**. So it only needs to read the documents that fall in between those bounds. The list of those documents **is** a part of the index.

Here is some code to easily reproduce:

```js
people = [
    "Marc", "Bill", "George", "Eliot", "Matt", "Trey", "Tracy",
    "Greg", "Steve", "Kristina", "Katie", "Jeff"];

for (var i=0; i<200000; i++){
    name = people[Math.floor(Math.random()*people.length)];
    age = Math.floor(Math.random() * ( 50 - 18 + 1)) + 18;
    boolean = [true,false][Math.floor(Math.random()*2)];
    db.names.insert({ 
        name: name,
        age: age,
        boolean: boolean,
        added: new Date() 
    }); 
}
```

Adding the index:

```js
db.names.ensureIndex( { name: 1, age: 1 });
```

And running the query:

```js
db.names.find({ 
    age: {$gte: 21, $lte: 30} 
}).hint( { name: 1, age: 1 } ).explain()
```

Will get you results something like:

```js
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor name_1_age_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 60226,
    "nscannedObjects" : 60226,
    "nscanned" : 60250,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 60226,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 60250,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 227,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "name" : [
                    [
                            {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            ],
            "age" : [
                    [
                            21,
                            30
                    ]
            ]
    },
    "server" : "ubuntu:27017"
}
```

So you can see that `nscanned` is higher than `n` yet less than the total documents. Which goes to show that the "bounds" were taken into consideration, and when outside of those bounds the match will return no more.

What is happening here? Why are less documents returned than are in the collection? Basically the essence of the question.

So consider this. You know that your compound index does **not** specify the field that is being matched first. But do not think of a compound index as a **joined** statement (more later) think of it as a list of elements. So it does have discrete values of the `age` field in there somewhere.

Next, we have a **large** number of documents to go through. So the optimizer is going to naturally **hate** to scan. But since we didn't give a condition to match or range on the **first** element of the compound index it's going to have to start doing so. So we begin to chug along. Now for a more visual demonstration.

> miss, miss, miss, hit, hit, "lots of hits", miss, miss, "more misses", **STOP**.

Why the STOP. This is an optimize condition. Since we had the *discrete* values of age, **and** determined a *bounds* exists within the chosen index the question gets asked.

> "Wait just one moment. I **should** be scanning these in order, **but** I just got a load of misses. I think I missed my bus stop".

Colloquially speaking, that is **exactly** what the optimizer does. And realizing it just when past the point where it will find any more matches it "jumps off the bus" and walks back home with the result. So the matches have been "exhausted" past the point where it can *reasonably* determine that there will be any further matches.

Of course if the index order of fields was flipped, so that age was first or the only consideration, then `nscanned` and `n` would match as there was a distinctly clear start and end point.

The purpose of explain is that it can *explain* what is happening when the query statement is analysed. In this has it has "told" you that since your query conditions *asked* for a range in your query **and** that range can be matched in an index then it will use that information in scanning the results.

So what happened here was, that given the bounds on the index that was being used to search, the optimiser had an "idea" of where to start and then where to end. And given the factors, once matches "No longer seem" to be found the matching is exhausted and the process "gives up" considering it was not going to find anything else that resides out of those bounds.

Any other conditions such as where you were wondering if you had documents without a username would be irrelevant and would only apply if the index was "sparse", and then they would not be in the index at all. And this is not a sparse index nor are there nulls. But that was never the important part of understanding why the query did not go through all the documents.

What you may be struggling with is that this is a compound index. But that is not like an index on "concatenated" terms, so the index has to scan the `username` + the `age`. Instead both the fields can be considered, as long as they can be considered in "order". Which is why the **explain** output shows that this has matched those bounds.

The [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#explain.indexBounds) is not stellar on this.but does define what `indexBounds` means.

---

### EDIT

The final statement is that that is the confirmed and intended behavior, and the claimed "Bug" is actually not a bug, but rather one that was introduced in the 2.6 release, which includes a major re-factor of the Index interface code. See [SERVER-13197](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13197) which was reported by me.

So the same results as shown can be achieved in 2.6 by altering the query like so:

```
 db.names.find({
      "name": { "$gt": MinKey, "$lt": MaxKey },
      "age": {$gte: 21, $lte: 30}  
 }).sort( { "name": 1, "age": 1 } ).explain()

{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor name_1_age_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 60770,
    "nscannedObjects" : 60770,
    "nscanned" : 60794,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 60770,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 60794,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 474,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 133,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "name" : [
                    [
                            {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            ],
            "age" : [
                    [
                            21,
                            30
                    ]
            ]
    },
    "server" : "ubuntu:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

This shows that by including the `MinKey` and `MaxKey` values over the first index element, then the optimizer correctly detects that the bounds on the second element can be used in the way that has been already described.

Of course, this is not required in earlier versions as the use of the `sort` is enough to both specify this index and for the optimizer to detect the bounds correctly without the explicit modification to the query.

As noted on the issue, the fix for this is intended for release in a future version.

Comment: It should have to read all usernames which actually means it should do a full index scan since compound indexes in MongoDB are hierarchical

Comment: @Sammaye The index is clipped by `indexBounds` so there are a certain number of index entries before the `age` value of 21 and after the `age` value of 30. Those entries **do not** get used. Hence there is less than the total documents in the collection returned. Understand?

Comment: The order part of your answer makes no sense, even if all usernames are in order MongoDB cannot know that it has reached the end of the range, the compound index is not sorted by the range but by the username as such it still would have to scan all usernames to understand the range.

Comment: Also your answer still does not explain the difference between nscanned, collection total and n in the explain

Comment: @Sammaye I am reading this book: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028031.do See the part about compound indexes i.e. see page 88 and the examples which precede it. I don't understand Neil's answer too. All my usernames are unique. I don't see how the compound index which is there on {username: 1, age: 1} can eliminate the need to look at all usernames.

Comment: @NeilLunn Hm, this is closest to my question: "But that is not like an index on "concatenated" terms, so the index has to scan the username + the age. Instead both the fields can be considered, as long as they can be considered in "order". But it kind of contradicts what's written in the book, I think. They say a compound index on fields {a, b} is first sorted by field a, and within each value for a is sorted by b.

Comment: I doubt it's about versioning but who knows. My version is 2.4.8.

Comment: @peter.petrov Please ignore the other commentary. Most important is the code that has been provided to reproduce. Is this kristina's book. It's kind of dated actually, that was probably even pre 2.2, but I could stand corrected on the version. But also the point is that the matching "exhausts" after a while as I have stated, and what is used to make that deterimation is the indexBounds. This is what I have been trying to say all along. Even if it has taken a while to get there.

Comment: @peter.petrov and yes, while I also have a 2.6 RC running, the code shown was run on 2.4.6 actually.

Comment: wait what if you add the sort on that query as well?

Comment: @NeilLunn I guess it exhausts it but I don't know why ;) provided what's written in the book. Just makes no sense to exhaust and stop earlier before it has checked all usernames (in my example). Again: "a compound index on fields {a, b} is first sorted by field a, and within each value for a is sorted by b" (at least according to the book).

Comment: @Sammaye run the code. It's pretty simple. sort() hint() doesn't matter. Only one index. But I've already answered that question today.

Comment: @peter.petrov Does this need more explaining? Tell me what you are not understanding and I'll try to fix it. It exhausts. Tick yes. Why less. It's using the "bounds". Beyond the bounds it stops. On a small collection it will just scan. This is more a "hang on a minute" moment where the optimizer decides to do something different  before doing more work.

Comment: This picture explains quite well why I am quite confused by this: http://blog.mongolab.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/IndexVisitation-4.png this quite accurately shows a compound index as such that is why I am confused how MongoDB knows the range of an inner on the outer, it is also what causes a scanandorder if you reverse the index since MongoDB has to manually sort a compound index in that case. Thisis what it all comes down to.

Comment: The book says if you have compound index on {a,b,c,d,e} it is as if it has indexes on all prefixes {a}, {a,b}, {a,b,c}, {a,b,c,d}. In my example it is not a prefix. This needs more explaining. No it is not clear to me, Neil. Sorry.

Comment: And I have no idea yet why in your example it scans just about 60,000 docs.

Comment: @peter.petrov Yes. I answered that today as well http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222357/252977

Comment: @peter.petrov I think I see a section where I could expand on the documents scanned part a bit more. Give me a few moments. Making my evening meal in between responses.

Comment: No hurry. Take your time.

Comment: This isn't changing the goal posts though, this is answering his original question, you answer somehow proves that MongoDB is somehow able to traverse from the middle of a compound index even when the documentation says it shouldn't. Your explanation doesn't stand to his scrutiny, that's not changing the question, that's wanting a canconical answer.

Comment: @Sammaye Yeah, no, I mean: I haven't changed my questions in any way. Sammaye, in the book I see this: "The index pattern of  {"sortKey" : 1, "queryCriteria" : 1} often works well in applications, as most application do not want all possible results for a query but only the first few. It also scales well because of the way indexes are organized internally. Indexes are basically trees, with the smallest value on the leftmost leaf and the greatest on the rightmost.". This matches perfectly with the diagram you posted a link to.

Comment: @peter.petrov I've gone as far as to post this on the user group, I mean even this 10gen presentation which is count as still valid describes compound indexes this way: http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/storage-engine-internals

Comment: @Sammaye Thanks. If you find out something, I would be thankful if you could post it as an answer. This is in no way related to my work, I am just reading this book and trying to understand it in details and not just superficially.

Comment: @Sammaye And if we talk about Neil's example: I don't get 2 things: 1) why it scans only about 60000 documents (provided there're 200000 in total); 2) why is nscanned only slightly bigger than n, this seems conceptually different than my example where nscanned is much much bigger than n (though I cannot tell where the conceptual difference is between our two examples). Actually it is not my example, it is the book's example. Note: the book is the 2nd edition, from 2013, so I doubt it is that much outdated, these are core, basic things.

Comment: @peter.petrov There are a few more paragraphs there under the (sample) output that may help to explain further. I don't know how better to explain this any more here aside from ripping sections of code, which would seem even more obtuse. Just try to understand this is an optimization that is meant to work this way. It's there to help.

Comment: OK, thanks, Neil. Appreciate your willingness to help. I will reread all this in 1 day or so, let's see if I get it better.

Comment: But that's crazy what if there is a hit right at the end after too many misses, if that's what it does in code that is actually quite bad

Comment: @Sammaye Exactly. This is what I was asking myself too :) Especially in my example it is so obvious because all usernames are unique: "user" + i, where i=0,1,...,199999. So how does it know that user199999 has no age of 22 let's say? I've never read much about indexes even in the context of relational DBs. So I am just asking basic questions here :)

Comment: @peter.petrov indeed MongoDB might actually lose a lot of my respect after that since I cannot state that any results I get of a cardinally sorted compound index (without in memory scan) is actually consistent

Comment: Well, I doubt it is that bad for such an obvious thing. I just think we're missing something here. I don't know what though.

Comment: @peter.petrov well I mean if you lose some of your result set because of this, then you lose consistentcy of results, also what about updating and deleting by this condition? You would inhibit massive consistentcy flaws

Comment: @peter.petrov I think that you are both missing the point. And it really is too much to go into here. Also I am sure that SO has many answers that would be better and there should be know need to reproduce. But B-Tree indexes are not linear, and all of this argument chain is debating expecting a linear result. For what it is worth, I've shot this link off to a few MongoDB employees to see if they have the resources to give a more succinct answer.

Comment: @peter.petrov Ok I know this now, I can explain Neils nscanned, it is actually the count of all name + count of the range under each username + some overlap, that is why his results are so much more varied to your own, because your names are unique where as his are not

Comment: @Sammaye OK, thanks but I think this is a bit too advanced for me at this stage ;) For now, I am happy I got good answer to the original question. Thanks.